# server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created two models

```
 public class ExpenseReport
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(10, 2)")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Required]
        public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Required]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

and

```
  public class ExpenseDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<ExpenseReport> ExpenseReport { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {

                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data source=database/listDb.db");
            }

        }
    }
```

after I wanted to create database 
so  I add-migration and after update-database I had this error:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
I want to create database in folder ->database  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xPNV.jpg -this is possible?

I tried
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017
but it didn't help

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and connect to database.  The Server/Instance and the type of Credentials (should be Windows) is on the login window.  Make sure you can access the database from the machine where you are running the c# application.  The connection string in c# should use same Server/Instance as login window.  The connection string should have Integrated Security = TRUE.  You will not need a user name or password.  You will not need the Attach statement in the connection string because the database is already connected to the Server.

Comment: `"Data source=database/listDb.db"` is not a valid connection string for SQL Server. It would be a valid connection string for an SQLite database. You will have to use `UseSqlite()` then though.

Comment: but I have to save my list.db in folder database-this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Connection with username and password:

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
"Data Source=ServerName;" +
"Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
"User id=UserName;" +
"Password=Secret;");
```

Or Trusted Connection:

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
"Data Source=ServerName;" +
"Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
"Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```